# PHP While Loop setting count ID

Tags: php

I'm a little stuck with a piece of PHP I am working on, I need to set the href of a link to the same ID for the DIV below it, but its not setting them the same.

```
$x=1; 
     while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
     if($color!='')
        {
            $out.='<'.$heading.' class="heading_accordion newHeadingColor">'.get_the_title().'</'.$heading.'>';
        }
     else
     {
                $out.='<dd class="accordion-navigation"><a href="#panel'.$x++.'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
     }
                $out.= '<div id="panel'.$x++.'" class="content">'.get_the_content().'</div></dd>';

                endwhile; // end of the loop.
```

its doing

```
<a href="#panel1">link</a>
<div id="panel2">content</div>
<a href="#panel3">link</a>
<div id="panel4">content</div>
<a href="#panel5">link</a>
<div id="panel6">content</div>
```

and need something like

```
<a href="#panel1">link</a>
<div id="panel1">content</div>
<a href="#panel2">link</a>
<div id="panel2">content</div>
<a href="#panel3">link</a>
<div id="panel3">content</div>
```

Comment: What is wrong with `the_ID();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are incrementing `$x` twice : Once when you output the href, once when you output the id.

You could just remove the incrementation on the first output :

```
$out.='<dd class="accordion-navigation"><a href="#panel'.$x.'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
```

And keep it in the second one :

```
$out.= '<div id="panel'.$x++.'" class="content">'.get_the_content().'</div></dd>';
```

Comment: Yea i tried that before but sets them all as 1 and never increases

Comment: @JamesBrandon Leave the `$x++` in the second part of course. Did  you ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
$x++;
     if($color!='')
        {
            $out.='<'.$heading.' class="heading_accordion newHeadingColor">'.get_the_title().'</'.$heading.'>';
        }
     else
     {
                $out.='<dd class="accordion-navigation"><a href="#panel'.$x.'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
     }
                $out.= '<div id="panel'.$x.'" class="content">'.get_the_content().'</div></dd>';

            endwhile; // end of the loop.
```

Answer (score 1):

> $x++

is equal to

> $x = $x + 1

so you increment this 2 times in 1 iteration. Try to remove increment from one of this two segments.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$x=1; 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

if($color!='') {
    $out.='<'.$heading.' class="heading_accordion newHeadingColor">'.get_the_title().'</'.$heading.'>';
} else {
    $out.='<dd class="accordion-navigation"><a href="#panel'.$x.'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
}
$out.= '<div id="panel'.$x.'" class="content">'.get_the_content().'</div></dd>';

$x++;
endwhile; // end of the loop.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the $x++ to early.

Just use $x to output the id and do $x++ after the if-else statement